# MongoDB between date range query - nested property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How to write query to return object between dates? Query should search nested property. I use `$gte` and `$lte` but it doesn't seem to work as I expected. I want to return 'task' object which has got history.startTime between two dates.

```
 db.tasks.find({'history.startTime' : { '$gte': ISODate("2017-02-04T00:00:00.000Z"), '$lt': ISODate("2017-02-05T23:00:00.000Z")} }).pretty()
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("588f53c5d00baa2558fd56ae"),
            "desc" : "test3",
            "category" : "Category1",
            "project" : "Project1",
            "_creator" : "582afb3800c1bc1f203edf39",
            "history" : [
                    {
                            "startTime" : ISODate("2017-02-06T11:49:42.570Z"),
                            "stopTime" : ISODate("2017-02-06T11:49:45.725Z"),
                            "_id" : ObjectId("589862d9449b4629f8dbaba7"),
                            "dt" : 3.155
                    },
                    {
                            "startTime" : ISODate("2017-02-06T08:53:53.086Z"),
                            "stopTime" : ISODate("2017-02-06T11:47:58.098Z"),
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5898626e449b4629f8dbaba6"),
                            "dt" : 10445.012
                    },
                    {
                            "startTime" : ISODate("2017-01-30T15:30:46.287Z"),
                            "stopTime" : ISODate("2017-01-30T15:32:52.979Z"),
                            "_id" : ObjectId("588f5c2cd00baa2558fd56b0"),
                            "dt" : 126.692
                    },
                    {
                            "startTime" : ISODate("2017-01-30T13:55:09.738Z"),
                            "stopTime" : ISODate("2017-01-30T14:55:13.974Z"),
                            "_id" : ObjectId("588f53d1d00baa2558fd56af"),
                            "dt" : 3604.236
                    }
            ],
            "isCompleted" : false,
            "isPerforming" : false,
            "duration" : 14179.095000000001,
            "updated" : ISODate("2017-02-06T11:49:45.725Z"),
            "creationDate" : ISODate("2017-01-30T14:55:01.045Z"),
            "__v" : 4
    }
```

Comment: It's not possible. Only you can do it manually or be using aggregate query via $unwind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an array. Your query won't work. You have to use $elemMatch.

```
db.tasks.find({
    'history': {
        $elemMatch: {
            startTime: {
                $gte: ISODate("2017-02-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
                $lte: ISODate("2017-02-05T23:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    }
});
```